# spring session rest security

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

Spring session seems like a very interesting project but I have not been able to find much information on how to properly incorporate it in a spring security application. The readme on project github page has some information but I dont think thats applicable to spring security. Another example thats mentioned on the same page is to utilize this mechanism for REST access. Thats another use case that i think can benefit from an example. I would appreciate if some information on the subject can be shared. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Session with Spring Security by simply ensuring to place the Spring Session Filter before Spring Security's filter. There is also an [security sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/b3130edd98537d866b7095ecd06b0cffc250c284/samples/security) that demonstrates the use of Spring Session with Spring Security within the distribution. You can run it by cloning the repository and running the following:

```
./gradlew :samples:security:tomcatRun
```

The application will be available at `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: i re-created this project using Maven. Works fine till packaging it as deploy-able WAR but when deployed in my WildFly8 HA Cluster, i get the following exception Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisServer' defined in class path resource [hello/EmbeddedRedisConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException    <br> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at redis.embedded.RedisServer.<init>(RedisServer.java:69)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using the embedded Redis since it wouldn't have much use on a clustered environment. Each node would have its own embedded redis... Replace the connection to redis with an external one and try again.